# Передать другой формат даты в MySQL

Tags: php

Приходит дата в формате 05.01.2016 . Как переконвертировать ее в формат типа 2016-01-05 средствами PHP

Comment: @Saidolim В указанном вами "дубликате" речь идет о работе с датой ИЗ mysql в Java. А тут из php В mysql ...

Comment: Вы серьезно? Поиском не пользовались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы уверены, что на входе корректная дата и ее контроль не нужен, то:

```
$date="05.01.2016";
$my_date=preg_replace("/(\d\d)\\.(\d\d)\\.(\d{4})/","$3-$2-$1",$date);
echo $my_date;
```

Или

```
$date="05.01.2016";
$arr=explode(".",$date);
$my_date=strftime("%F",mktime(0,0,0,$arr[1],$arr[0],$arr[2]));
echo $my_date;
```

Comment: спасибо помогли)) надо учить регулярки

Answer (score 3):

Если вопрос только в преобразовании даты, а не в том как её хранить в MySQL, то самый короткий вариант:

date('Y-m-d', strtotime('05.01.2015'));

Comment: Имхо этот вариант лучше

Comment: только боюсь strtotime зависит от настроек даты в php.ini и может давать неожиданные результаты при переезде на другой хостинг например

Comment: @Mike пока со странным поведением этой функции не встречался, сколько ей пользуюсь
[http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes]
`Замечание: 

Даты в формате m/d/y или d-m-y разрешают неоднозначность с помощью анализа разделителей их элементов: если разделителем является слеш (/), то дата интерпретируется в американском формате m/d/y, если же разделителем является дефис (-) или точка (.), то подразумевается использование европейского форматаd-m-y.`